# JSON "return JSON()" Fix MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null,FormMethod.Post , new {@class="form-horizontal"}))
                                        {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;
         Save
     </button>
}     

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home/EditProfile",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(m),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data == "Hello")
                    {
                     alert("Hello");
                    }

                    if (data=="error")
                    {

                }
            },
            error: function (data) { console.log(data) } 
        });


 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EditProfile(ModelUserProfile m)
        {

                   return Json("Hello");

        }
```

Okay what its return is the following page:
[image: Fix]

That is "Hello" written on the Blank Page?

But it should gimme alert "Hello". What is wrong??
Note: I am using  because of @html.BeginForm()

Comment: Impossible to read your image! How are you calling this ajax function? Is it from a `<input type="submit" ../>`? (in which case your probably making an ajax call but still doing the normal submit because you have not cancelled the default action)

Comment: Write click the image and open in new tab u can see it by Zooming :) and yes its <input type="submit>

Comment: Try with `<input type="button">`

Comment: Then you need to show the html for the button. And don't expect us to open your image! Just delete it - its pointless. And to solve the issue, make it a button or add `return false;` at the end of the script

Comment: i have update the HTML. Kindly review it

Comment: And `return false;` has not fixed the problem :) @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then you have added it in the correct place. Easiest to just change your html to `<button type="button" ...>` so its not doing a submit. You should also show the full script (how are your actually calling it)?

Answer (score -1):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <button type="button" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;
            Save
        </button>
    }



<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var m = {};
        m.name = "Ravi"; //What ever the object mention the properties //properly
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Home/EditProfile",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(m),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "Hello") {
                        alert("Hello");
                    }

                    if (data == "error") {

                    }
                },
                error: function (data) { console.log(data) }
            });
        });
    });

</script>


**Controller**

      public ActionResult EditProfile()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditProfile(ModelUserProfile m)
        {
            return Json("Hello");
        }
```